# Convert an aware datetime's timezone to UTC with zoneinfo (migration away from pytz)

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, zoneinfo

I am using Python 3.8, so I am using https://pypi.org/project/backports.zoneinfo/ to get zoneinfo. Django is deprecating the use of `pytz` so I am performing the change from `pytz` to `zoneinfo`

With pytz one would do `from pytz import UTC`. The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#using-zoneinfo) gets it from `datetime.timezone.utc` (and this does not have a `localize` method).

How does one perform the equivalent of this:
`pytz.UTC.localize(my_datetime, is_dst=None)`
With zoneinfo?

Comment: Maybe the deprecation shim can get you going? https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (besides, with UTC you don't need to localize, even with pytz. You can just set the tzinfo directly)

Comment: `pytz: The Fastest Footgun in the West` ... so funny =)

Answer (score 9):

pytz.localize is for naive datetimes (datetime with no timezone information) only, so

```
import datetime
import pytz
my_datetime = datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 31, 2)
pytz.UTC.localize(my_datetime, is_dst=None)
# -> datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 31, 2, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

The corresponding pytz-less construct is

```
my_datetime.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
# -> datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 31, 2, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Note: Do **not** use `my_datetime.astimezone(timezone.utc)` as this will assume my_datetime is represented in the system time zone.

Comment: The question was how to a convert a datetime's timezone to UTC, your answer assumes one has a naive datetime (i.e. has no timezone).

Answer (score 0):

The link @MrFuppes provides: https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html explains that pytz with its localize method was none standard. Now with zone info we can use an easy standard API without worry about shooting oneself in the foot:

`pytz.UTC.localize(my_datetime, is_dst=None)`

becomes

```
my_datetime.astimezone(timezone.utc)
```

And date arithmetic now works even with none UTC datetimes.

For @Wolfgang Kuehn

```py
Python 3.9.17 (main, Jun  6 2023, 20:11:21) 

from datetime import datetime, timezone
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
my_datetime = datetime(2021, 10, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Africa/Johannesburg'))
my_datetime.astimezone(timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 30, 22, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

As you can see there is a 2hr diff between `Africa/Johannesburg` and UTC

Comment: Please run your code to confirm that it is wrong, probably.

Comment: @WolfgangKuehn been working for years, I updated the answer to show the result of running the code

Comment: If `my_datetime` is naive, the result of `my_datetime.astimezone(timezone.utc)` and `my_datetime.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)` is the same